# Migrating email from old server without domain name with imapsync

Tags: email, migration, imap, imapsync

Here is the problem :

My client moved to another server, and they have changed domain name servers already. Old server is still active. Problem is that I have to migrate massive amount of email accounts, and another problem is they don't have cPanel credentials so my only option is to connect to each account individually and move the messages.

I wanted to use `imapsync` to do the migration but it can't connect to old server for some reason.

I have modified my `hosts` file on local machine and setup `mail.domain.com` to point to old ip address for smtp server and tried to connect with **outlook and it worked** (made sure it reads messages from the old server).

So I don't know why `imapsync` doesn't work since I've successfully connected with outlook on port `143`.

This is how I ran the command (I'm running it from my server where I have also modified `hosts` file) :

```
imapsync --host1 mail.domain.com --user1 email@domain.com -password1 pass --host2 localhost --user2 email@domain.com --password2 pass
```

It connects successfully to my localhost but when it tries to connec to old server this is what I get :

```
Info: turned ON syncinternaldates, will set the internal dates (arrival dates) on host2 same as host1.
Host1: will try to use LOGIN authentication on host1
Host2: will try to use LOGIN authentication on host2
Host1: imap connexion timeout is 120 seconds
Host2: imap connexion timeout is 120 seconds
Host1: IMAP server [mail.domain.com] port [143] user [email@domain.com]
Host2: IMAP server [localhost] port [143] user [email@domain.com]
Host1: connecting and login on host1 [mail.domain.com] port [143] with user [email@domain.com]
Host1 failure: can not open imap connection on host1 [mail.domain.com] with user [email@domain.com]: Unable to connect to mail.domain.com:
```

**tl;dr;**

**I have scanned old mail server IP on port 143 with `nmap` and `imap` is running properly. I can connect to old server with outlook and fetch emails, but `imapsync` is saying he can't connect?**

EDIT :

Just to note, I have tried connecting to mail server with out modifing hosts by using ip of old mail server but it didn't work.

Comment: Just a few troubleshooting tips. I know you said you connected using Outlook on 143 but have you double checked that you didn't have it at 143 then set up SSL (which changes port perhaps unnoticed?). Can you see the connection via Netstat? The other thing is that I believe there's specific encryption options in imapsync that you may be needing in there?

Comment: I have tested this imapsync locally on my pc (kind of messy to set up on windows) and it works. It would seem like there is some kind of setup which prevents me from talking to other servers that listen on port 143 from my server. I'm not sure how to circumvent this. I'm guessing I could do some kind of tunnel but I don't know how to do that exactly.

Answer (score 1):

your example command says you are trying to sync mails to local machine which will not work unless you have a imap server which can be looked up via internet, also in your command --host2 should have a public imap server name not localhost. You could follow [this article](https://gkitsystems.com/index.php/migrate-emails-using-imapsync/)

Srivishnu.K

Answer (score -1):

nmap just says port 143 is open, it does not mean that imap works properly at all. Since you changed the server hostnames for host1, we can't help that much. This error can come from bad typo in hostname, bad link, firewall between.
Try tls encryption with:

```
imapsync ... --tls1
```

or try ssl encryption with:

```
imapsync ... --ssl1
```

If it doesn't work, it means the problem is the connection. 
Try a manual telnet with:

```
telnet mail.domain.com 143
A1 LOGIN email@domain.com secret
A2 LOGOUT
```

Anyway "Unable to connect to mail.domain.com" means the connection (hostname or port or link) is the problem. telnet should show the same error.

Comment: tried it, doesn't work

Comment: Your answer would be much more helpful if you could include some information about what the commands are supposed to do and why the asker should run the commands.